# Nested loops, two-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pygame, nested-loops

I have a text document where only 1 and 0 are written in the form of an 80 by 80 square, i.e. 80 lines and 80 columns where only 1 and 0 are written. I need to create a code that draws an 80 by 80 square and fills those boxes in red, instead of which 1.

```py
import pygame
import os
# create path to find my document

path = os.path.realpath('future.txt')
task = open(path, mode = 'r',encoding = 'utf-8')
#create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))

white = [255, 255, 255]
red = [255, 0, 0]

x = 0
y = 0
#intepreter string as a list
for line in task:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    line = list(line)

# nested loop
    for j in range(0,80):

        for i in range(0,79):

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (x, y, 10, 10), 1)

            x += 10


            if line[i] == '1':
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (x, y, 9, 9))


            if x == 800:
                x = 0
                y += 10

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This is my code yet. Python version 3.

Comment: Please specify your question.

Comment: There is a bag in my code. It draws an only 1st line for my pygame square. I think it happened in my nested loop, but I can't understand what's wrong. My question is where is this bag and how should I change my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one nested loop to much. Only 2 nested loops are needed to traverse a 2 dimensional array.

The liens are traversed by:

> ```
> for line in task:
>     line = line.replace('\n', '')
> ```

And the columns are traversed by

> ```
> for j in range(0,80):
> ```

Change your code like this:

```py
y = 0
for line in task:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')

    x = 0
    for elem in list(line):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (x, y, 10, 10), 1)
        if elem == '1':
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (x+1, y+1, 8, 8))
        x += 10

    y += 10
```